# Setting build priority in yaml or UI

Tags: build, azure-devops

Is there a way to setup up a build's priority in a yaml based pipeline? There seem to be references to build priority in the [Azure DevOps API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/Builds/Update%20Builds?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#queuepriority), but nothing in how to do this via yaml. I thought there might be some docs in the [Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) section, but no.

We need this because we have some fast building NuGet packages, but these get starved via slow-build pipelines making turnaround time for packages painful.

The closest thing I could come up with to working around this is via agent demands in the yaml

```
demands:
  - Agent.ComputerName = XYZ
```

to separate build pipelines, but this is a bit of a hack and doesn't use agents efficiently.

A way to set this in UI would be acceptable, but I couldn't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Setting build priority in yaml or UI

I'm afraid this feature is not yet supported in Azure DevOps at this moment.

There is a popular [user voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365507/ability-to-set-build-priority.html) about it, you can upvote it and check the feedback from that ticket.

Currently as a workaround, just like what you did, set the [demands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/options#demands) in build definitions to force building with the specific agents.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It may be concerning for some DevOps users that the uservoice item in question hasn't had any MSFT feedback (other than a MSFT-named account upvoting it) or transitioned out of "New" state, since it was migrated two years ago...

Answer (score 8):

Recently Azure DevOps introduced the ability to [manually specify a build/release runs next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-175-update#run-this-job-next).

This manifests as a Run next button. ([image source](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ability-to-set-build-priority/365507#T-N1546830)).

[image]

So while you can't say "this pipeline always takes priority" yet, you can manually force a specific run to the front of the queue.

If you need a specific pipeline to always take priority, then you likely want to setup a [separate agent pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser) just for those pipelines, or [use demands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) as Leo Liu mentioned.